# Response issue in codeigniter & MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have a set up that I require a count on a collection, I just keep getting an error of

> {"status":false}

My model looks like:

```
public function count_users() {

        $query = $this->mongo_db->get('users');
        $row_count = count($query);

        $data = $row_count;

        $return = [
            'status' => true,
            'data'   => $data
        ];
    }
```

and my controller is such :

```
// **
    // ** List Todays Stats for Admin Panel
    // **
    public function todaysstats_get() {
        //Validate user - logged in as admin -- session required
        $this->session_model->check_session();

        //Count Users
        $data           = $this->admin_model->count_users();

        $http           = $this->data_model->status_to_http_response($data['status']);
        $data['status'] = $http['status'];
        $http_response  = $http['http_response'];

        $this->set_response($data, $http_response);
    }
```

I'm using a `GET` method to get the simple count return number

```
$route['v1/admin/todaysstats'] = 'v1/admin/todaysstats';
```

I have tried a few different ways but it just doesn't seem to change the status on the `REST` request.

The method for `$http = $this->data_model->status_to_http_response($data['status']);`

```
 public function status_to_http_response($status) {

        // Select appropriate HTTP Response code, based on "status"
        // true  ---> 200
        // false ---> 422 (usually a validation error)
        // else  ---> use the value in "status" and set "status" to false.
        $status = intval($status);


        // If "true" send back a 200
        if ($status == 1) { 
            $http = REST_Controller::HTTP_OK;
            $status = true;
        }
        // If "false" send back a 422
        elseif ($status == 0) {
            $http = REST_Controller::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;
            $status = false;
        }
        // Otherwise use the status code given
        else {
            $http   = $status;
            $status = false;
        }

        return [
                'http_response' => $http,
                'status'        => $status,
                ];
    }
```

Comment: What does `$this->data_model->status_to_http_response()` do? Since you're overwriting the `status` with the status from that method, that's what you should post. Currently, it's impossible for us to know what's going on.

Comment: added to question

Comment: Why are you converting the boolean `$status` to an integer? Skip that and just do `if ($status) { ... } else { ... }`. Also, there's no need for `elseif()` and then an `else`. It's a boolean. It only have two states.

Comment: This was set up by the back end developer , Im just trying to add some methods to it, its a nightmare

Comment: Bounce it back to the back end developer. This makes zero sense. 1. The method `count_users()` will _always_ return `true` as status since it's hard coded. 2. Since you're getting a boolean, it can only have two states, which makes the last `else` redundant. 3. Since you just want to check the current status (which is a boolean), there's no reason to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Yeah , I wanted to use Laravel lol Its a nightmare! Ok thanks